# Execute Runtime.getRuntime().exec(... command at server and get the client results

Tags: java

I want to check the tasks running on my clients, to avoid illegal programs from been executed

Is there a way to do that?

The code im trying to apply is:

```
try {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
    BufferedReader input = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line); //<-- Parse data here.
    }
    input.close();
} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java

Comment: @FastSnail : if I correctly understand the question, OP wants the list of applications running on client. This has only sense in an applet or with JavaScript ...

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist");`

Comment: @FastSnail ive seen this topic. but i dont want to check the server machine tasks i want to check my client taks!!

Comment: @SergeBallesta exactly!!

Comment: @ΜάνοςΣταθόπουλος then javascript applet will do that.not sure about javascript .is that web application ?

Comment: @ΜάνοςΣταθόπουλος http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101364/javascript-to-get-running-processes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018438/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-running-processes-using-an-applet

Comment: @FastSnail it is a java application for a gameserver

Comment: @ΜάνοςΣταθόπουλος ok where your game open?in browser or you have a game application running in client computer ?